# Grafana chart link - format html?

Tags: grafana

I'm using Grafana's table chart, and have formatted a column to be a Link. There's a usability issue in that users don't know the column is a link unless they hover over it.
Is there a way to format the html of Grafana table chart links?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is not supported directly in Grafana table plugin yet.

You can try to make cell "look like link" adding some html markup to cell value in query:

`SELECT concat('<u>',name,'</u>') from enumerations`

and set column style to `String` type and check option `Sanitize HTML`.

This is ugly solution, it depends on what is supported in datasource and may not work well in your case. I tried it in Grafana 5.0.x and postgres only.

Comment: thanks Yuri - unfortunately in my case i need to pass the cell's exact value to the link as a parameter, so can't modify its value.

Comment: Dirty hack would be to add a hidden duplicate column with unmodified value and use it for URL construction.